# Why does my FBX model scale 100x when exporting to GLB?

Tags: export, .fbx

I have a simple model in FBX, when I export it to a GLB file it comes out scaled 100x too big.

Is there a setting on export that I am missing?

Comment: did you apply your scale before?

Comment: I ended up having to apply a scale in blender after import to get the export to be correct scale.